# R - Writing individual values in a matrix using matching to create vector of coordinates in R

Tags: r, matrix, match, coordinates, overwrite

Say I create a matrix of 0 with specified number of rows and columns:

```
r = 100
c = 100
zero_mat = matrix(rep(0, r*c),r,c)
```

I also have a vector with the names of US states that's 100 rows long, it looks like:

```
states[1:7,1] #structured as a matrix with 1 column and many rows
California 
Arizona 
Wisconsin             
California         
Washington 
Washington 
Washington
```

So, then let's say I just make the column names of zero_mat the names of the states:

```
colnames(zero_mat) = t(unique(states))
```

> Now, here's the question. How do I write a 1 to elements in zero_map
>   corresponding to the row the state is in, in `states` and the column
>   corresponding to the name of the state?

I'm sure it's just 1 line of code, but I've spend a couple hours trying to figure it out to no avail. I thought this might work: `zero_mat[1:r, states[1:r,1]] = 1`, but it just returns a matrix of 1's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly. Let's say this is your data:

```
states = c('Ca', 'Ar', 'Wi', 'Ca', 'Wa', 'Wa', 'Wa')
```

and your `zero_mat` and its column names are defined like this:

```
states_uniq = unique(states)
zero_mat = matrix(0, ncol=length(states_uniq), nrow=length(states))
colnames(zero_mat) = states_uniq

##      Ca Ar Wi Wa
## [1,]  0  0  0  0
## [2,]  0  0  0  0
## [3,]  0  0  0  0
## [4,]  0  0  0  0
## [5,]  0  0  0  0
## [6,]  0  0  0  0
## [7,]  0  0  0  0
```

You can use `match` to find the position of `states` within `states_uniq`

```
match(states, states_uniq)
## [1] 1 2 3 1 4 4 4
```

These will be the column indices of the `1`s you want to set in `zero_mat`. The corresponding row indices are simply `1:length(states)`. So the row and column indices of your `1`s, collected in the rows of a 2-column matrix are as follows:

```
cbind(1:length(states), match(states, states_uniq))
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    1
## [2,]    2    2
## [3,]    3    3
## [4,]    4    1
## [5,]    5    4
## [6,]    6    4
## [7,]    7    4
```

This 2-column matrix can be used to index `zero_mat` and set the corresponding entries to `1`:

```
zero_mat[ cbind(1:length(states), match(states, states_uniq)) ] = 1

##      Ca Ar Wi Wa
## [1,]  1  0  0  0
## [2,]  0  1  0  0
## [3,]  0  0  1  0
## [4,]  1  0  0  0
## [5,]  0  0  0  1
## [6,]  0  0  0  1
## [7,]  0  0  0  1
```

If the dataset is large, you might want to use a sparse matrix from the `Matrix` package to save space:

```
Matrix::sparseMatrix(i=1:length(states), 
                     j=match(states, states_uniq), 
                     x=1, 
                     dimnames=list(NULL, states_uniq))

## 7 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##      Ca Ar Wi Wa
## [1,]  1  .  .  .
## [2,]  .  1  .  .
## [3,]  .  .  1  .
## [4,]  1  .  .  .
## [5,]  .  .  .  1
## [6,]  .  .  .  1
## [7,]  .  .  .  1
```